# CUDA memcpy not working when copying back to host

Tags: c#, cuda

my problem is CUDA memcpy copying back from device to host. My program uses GUI written in C# + CUDA wrapper class and core cuda logic written in cudaC.

This is the main code in c# responsible for starting everything:

```cs
int[] imgData = srcImg.RgbData8bitInt;
int[] patData = pattern.PatternData;
int[] maskData = pattern.MaskData;
int[] Accumulator = new int[srcImg.Width * srcImg.Height];

IntPtr A_dev = CUDA.MallocInt(srcImg.Width * srcImg.Height);

IntPtr Img_dev = CUDA.MallocInt(imgData.Length);
CUDA.MemcpyToDevice(imgData, Img_dev, imgData.Length);

IntPtr Pat_dev = CUDA.MallocInt(patData.Length);
CUDA.MemcpyToDevice(patData, Pat_dev, patData.Length);

IntPtr Mask_dev = CUDA.MallocInt(maskData.Length);
CUDA.MemcpyToDevice(maskData, Mask_dev, maskData.Length);

int gridSizeX = (srcImg.Width - pattern.Image.Width) / 256 + 1;
int gridSizeY = srcImg.Height - pattern.Image.Width;
int imageWidth = srcImg.Width;

CUDA.Execute(status, gridSizeX, gridSizeY, A_dev, Img_dev, Pat_dev, Mask_dev, imageWidth);
CUDA.SynchronizeContext();

CUDA.MemcpyToHost(Accumulator, A_dev, Accumulator.Length);
```

Btw. the CUDA.SynchronizeContext() is wrapper for cudaThreadSynchronize();

The problematic part is the last line, responsible for copying values from device back to host.

```cs
[DllImport(dllPath, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int memcpyToHost(int[] srcPtr, IntPtr devPtr, int size);
```

```c
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall memcpyToHost(int* host, int* dev, int size)
{
    if (dev == 0) return 1;
    cudaError_t status = cudaMemcpy(host, dev, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (status == cudaSuccess)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

The error status i'm getting while debugging is: cudaErrorInvalidValue

Allocating memory and copying to device seems ok, i've debugged. I'm completly at loss here, maybe someone encountered similar problem?

**EDIT: SOLVED** See comments

Comment: It's possible that the error is arising from a previous CUDA call or kernel call.  Are you doing appropriate kernel error checking and/or error checking in the wrapper function around `cudaThreadSynchronize()`?  Note that SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions like these ("why isn't my code working?"), that you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also note that `cudaThreadSynchronize()` is deprecated in favor of `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, but that is certainly not causing a problem here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Acutally I've struggeld with this problem for few days, but I solved it just now. The issue was cudaDeviceReset(); placed right after kernel call... ... ...

Comment: If you provide an answer to explain what the problem was and how you fixed it, then we can get this question off the unanswered list.  (Yes, you can answer your own question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was cudaDeviceReset(); placed right after kernel call.